# MongoDB - MapReduce one collection into second collection

Tags: mongodb, mapreduce

I have two collections:

- Order: { _id, OrderId, Parameters, [default empty ***Summary***] etc. }
- Batch: { _id, OrderId, Phase1 { Planned, Done }, Phase2 { Planned, Done}, etc. }

Order have 0..n batches ("production batch"). (I'm using _id and "OrderId" because is from external system.)

I'm doing map-reduce on "Batch".

Result is:

```
{
_id: ORDER_ID, 
value: {
    Phase1: {Planned: 100, Done: 60},
    Phase2: {Planned: 60, Done: 20}
}
```

in collection "order_summary".

How can I insert this result into collection "Order" (exactly: Order.Summary)? Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

Map-Reduce is about *aggregation* and not about *modification*. Further operations based on the result of a Map-Reduce operation is up to you and your code and completely outside the scope of MR.

Comment: Thanks for reply. I do this with map-reduce to "order_summary" collection with DBRef to "order" collection.

Answer (score 0):

It's not really designed for this purpose, but have you tried to use a finalize function to do this for you?  Otherwise, the normal place to do this work is in client-side code that runs when the map-reduce is finished.

Comment: I have another map-reduce so I keep it in separate collections with DBRef to "order" collection.